# Is it correct to train and validate the model on F1-score metrics?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, time-series, training, f1score

I am trying to do experiments on multiple data sets. Some are more imbalanced than others. Now, in order to assure fair reporting, we compute F1-Score on test data. In most machine learning models, we train and validate the model via accuracy measure metric. However, this time, I decided to train and validate the model on an F1-score metric measure. Technically, there should be no problems, in my opinion. However, I am wondering if this is the correct approach to go.

Second, when I use this method (training, validation on F1-score), I receive a higher loss error and a lower F1-score on training data than on validation data. I’m not sure why.

Comment: Are you sure that the class imbalance is a problem? [Statisticians do not see class imbalance as such a problem, so long as you use the proper statistical methods (which are the same in both balanced and imbalanced problems).](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)

Answer (score -1):

In case of imbalanced class, Accuracy should never be used. As a model can just say every observation belongs to majority class and still gets very high accuracy.

For evaluating imbalanced class we use Precision, Recall or F1-score based on whatever metrics align best with out business objective. If you are getting low F1-Score it means that model is not able to perform well. To tackle the low F1-score please try following :

```
Sampling : Try to balance the data by using UpSampling or downsampling techniques
Class Weights : Use class weights parameter in ML algorithm to assign weights to classes
Data Augmentation : Use data augmentation techniques like SMOTE to generate more examples
```

Comment: What's the problem with getting high accuracy when the classes are imbalanced?

Comment: Because suppose you are predicting credit card default, 99% do not do fraud and only 1% do fraud. Now in this if model says that no one does fraud it still have a 99% accuracy, though model is very bad

Comment: You get $99\%$ accuracy. "Rats! We're only at our baseline." What's the problem? Setting aside the issues with accuracy outlined in the link I posted, this only seems like a problem if you give the number without context.